# Exception: You do not have permission to access the requested document calling web app from Google Spreadsheet (GAS) as a non-owner user

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-oauth

I have created a Google Spreadsheet which includes protected ranges, therefore, domain users cannot perform certain tasks, for instance sorting the sheet.
As such, I have created a web app which runs under my account (admin) and does this. Trial and error got it to work, when I am running the script.
The issue is that when other domain users are invoking the web app the following error is thrown:

[image]

Google Spreadsheet code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var m = ui.createMenu('Extra');
  m.addItem('↑↓ Surname','sortByName');
  m.addItem('↑↓ Section','sortBySection');
  m.addItem('↑↓ DOB','sortByDOB');
  m.addToUi();
}

function sortByName(){
  sortSheet("byName");
}
function sortBySection(){
  sortSheet("bySection");
} 
function sortByDOB(){
  sortSheet("byDOB");
}

function sortSheet(sortType){
  if (!isClassSheet()){
    return;
  }
  var sheet = aS.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetId = aS.getId();
  var baseUrl ="https://script.google.com/a/macros/ourdomain.com/s/xxxx/exec"
  var queryString = "?sheetID="+sheetId+"&sortType="+sortType+"&sheetName="+sheet.getName()+"&firstDataRow="+FIRST_DATA_ROW+"&classColStudentName="+S_CLASS_COL_STUDENT_NAME+"&classColSection="+S_CLASS_COL_SECTION+"&classColDOB="+S_STUDENTS_COL_DOB;
  var url = encodeURI(baseUrl + queryString)
  var params = {method: "get", headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params)
    //logsheet.appendRow([request])
  Logger.log(request)
}
```

Unbound Web App code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var param = e.queryString;
  var parameters = param.split("&")  // This just checks only 7 parameters are present else gives a invalid link

  if (param != null && parameters.length == 7){
    param = e.parameter;
    var sheetId = param.sheetID;
    var name = param.sheetName;
    var sortType = param.sortType;
    var S_CLASS_COL_STUDENT_NAME = Number(param.classColStudentName);
    var S_CLASS_COL_SECTION = Number(param.classColSection);
    var S_STUDENTS_COL_DOB = Number(param.classColDOB);
    var FIRST_DATA_ROW = Number(param.firstDataRow);
  } else {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Bad")
    }
  try{  
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId)  
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name)
     var dataRange = sheet.getRange(FIRST_DATA_ROW,1,(sheet.getLastRow() - FIRST_DATA_ROW + 1),sheet.getLastColumn()); 
     
     switch (sortType){
       case "byName":
          dataRange.sort({column: S_CLASS_COL_STUDENT_NAME, ascending: true});
          break;
       case "bySection":
          dataRange.sort([{column: S_CLASS_COL_SECTION, ascending: true}, {column: S_CLASS_COL_STUDENT_NAME, ascending: true}]);
          break;  
       case "byDOB":
          dataRange.sort([{column: S_STUDENTS_COL_DOB, ascending: true}, {column: S_CLASS_COL_STUDENT_NAME, ascending: true}]);
          break;   
     }
     
     }
     catch (err){
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(err)
     }
 return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success")
}
```

Deployment settings

[image]

Comment: Did you published the webapp with to access as `even, anonymous` settings? and are user accessing that `exec` url?

Comment: Also `UrlFetchApp` can only access publicly available URL, from what I see in code, you're trying to `fetch` dev url

Comment: Edited, I have changed the code to use the deployment version and now the error has changed. I have included the deployment settings in the OP

Comment: You have to change the baseurl also, that base url should be published webapp url. with setting as `even, anonymous`. Currently you're using  `/dev`  version of it

Comment: Is that script attached to sheet, means is it a container bound script?

Comment: The script which is calling the web app is bound to a sheet, whilst the web app is unbound

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. `doGet` executed successfully and returned `Success` when I called it via `sortSheet`, with an out of domain user. Can you provide some information about the context in which `sortSheet` is called? Is it directly from the script editor, or via button, custom menu, etc.? Considering that the calling script is bound to a spreadsheet, I assume that the out of domain users executing this have access to the spreadsheet. Is that correct?

Comment: Custom menu items in the spreadsheet are firing GAS functions, which in turn will invoke `SortSheet`. Web App is deployed to allow only domain users, and the spreadsheet is shared only amongst domain users which is the case. Edited OP to include menus and calling functions

Comment: I think problem is with this line ` var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId)` , you should try to log some parameters you're passing like `aS,sheetID,sheetName` and check that, also remove the `params` from `UrlFetchApp`,

Comment: When removing `params`, the script will fail running (nothing happens, and I cannot further investigate as we don't have cloud logging enabled to debug the web app). `aS,sheetID,sheetName` are fine, these will perfectly work when the script is run under my account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's interested in this, I have read [this document](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script) which explains that the web app must be shared with users who are invoking it through the spreadsheet. Thanks to @TheMaster for pointing it out and to @Tanaike for writing the document